# complex number Argand plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Please provide me some hits how to solve below problem.

> ABCD is a parallelogram on the Argand plane. The affixes of $A,B,C$ are 
>       $8+5i,-7-5i,-5+5i$, respectively .Find the affix of D.

Comment: Hint: complex numbers add like vectors.

Comment: Another hint: Think of the addition of vectors AND the characteristics of the parallelogram to attain your D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate the 3 points on the plane and use the fact that a parallelogram has 2 pairs of equal and parallel sides to determine the 4th.

Comment: >  yes that right, I was doing same way but taking $i$ also while considering point as $x,y$ . Now , I am got $x = 10 and y = -5,10 $ . so I came with two answer $10+15i and 10-5i $ but in book the answer is $10+15i$ .just wondering why another one is missing ?